# How to use Laravel Eloquent model in core PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I am developing a project in core PHP and I want to use eloquent query structure in my project to make ease of setting up mySQL connections and executing mySQL queries .

Comment: You would probably be better of searching for something like 'php how to use eloquent without laravel'

Comment: Checkout Mattstaufers `Torch` repository: https://github.com/mattstauffer/Torch 
It's not really up-to-date yet but yet could give some valuable insight to do it on your own.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Start by using `composer require illuminate/database vlucas/phpdotenv`
2. create a bootstrap file to bootstrap `Eloquent`'s connection string:

   ```
   //bootstrap.php
   <?php

       require 'vendor/autoload.php';

       use Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager as Capsule;

       $dotenv = new Dotenv\Dotenv(__DIR__);
       $dotenv->load();

       $capsule = new Capsule;

       $capsule->addConnection([
           'driver'    => env('DB_CONNECTION'),
           'host'      => env('DB_HOST'),
           'port'      => env('DB_PORT'),
           'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE'),
           'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME'),
           'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD'),
           'charset'   => 'utf8',
           'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
           'prefix'    => '',
       ]);

       $capsule->setAsGlobal();

       $capsule->bootEloquent();
   ```
3. Add environment variables!! (*.env file*)
4. Create a model file, you can put this anywhere you want

   ```
   //Models/User.php
   <?php

       namespace Models;

       use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

       class User extends Model
       {

       }
   ```
5. Use them!

   ```
   <?php 
       require('bootstrap.php');

       use Models\User;
       use Illuminate\Database\Connection as DB;

       $user = User::find(1);

       $user2 = User::where('name', 'somename')->first();
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You can use opensource project  http://www.phptomb.com
You can customise the existing class to meet your requirements.

Comment: Why would they want to use another project to use eloquent?

Comment: Because eloquent ask to install whole bunch of libraries and phptomb is just a single class file. Easy to use, easy to customise, For beginners especially.

Comment: you can use Eloquent as is. please see my answer below

Comment: If someone with core php know composer and elequant file, he would be using laravel. But a fresher with no framework knowledge and oops depth knowledge can use phptomb. Really admire answer of joe, right way to adopt elequant if you know a little of laravel framework and composer.