# Use Laravel 8 app function outside the Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I have a Laravel application inside my website's sub-folder (`laravel`). The structure is as follow:

```
/css
/images
/js
/laravel
  /app
    /Http
      /Controllers
        TaskController.php
    /Models
      User.php
    ..etc
  artisan
  /bootstrap
  /config
  server.php
  ..etc
index.php
```

I would like to make use of the class `User.php` and the CRUD functions in `TaskController.php` in my `index.php`. How can I do so?

Comment: I am not clear your problem properly. You may use `/Laravel/app/Models/User.php`

Comment: For example, in the Controller, I can update the properties of the model to database using `edit()` function.

Comment: What is your problem ? State it please

Comment: @matiaslauriti see the comment above. I just want to make use of Laravel CRUD controller to update properties in the DB, outside the Laravel app (see the structure above). Do I have to include the "autoload"?

Comment: Can you show how your `TaskController` and `index.php` file looks like.

Comment: @Raptor so you are trying to do a simple CRUD and you don't understand the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#basic-routing) ? Do you have anything coded ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53425891/how-to-use-laravel-eloquent-model-in-core-php/53426230

Comment: @matiaslauriti please read the question *carefully*. I have already mentioned that the Laravel app is complete, and I just want to use it OUTSIDE the Laravel folder. The documentation you quoted is irrelevant, as it is still INSIDE the Laravel folder.

Comment: @ibrahim-dogan your reference link is very useful, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I post as an answer so that people in the future might be benefited.*

I refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53426230/188331), my steps are as follow:

1. install required libraries using `composer`:
2. create a `bootstrap.php` in parallel with `index.php`：

**bootstrap.php**

```
<?php
require_once('vendor/autoload.php');

use Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager as Capsule;

$dotenv = Dotenv\Dotenv::createImmutable(__DIR__ . '/../laravel/');
$dotenv->load();

$capsule = new Capsule();

$capsule->addConnection([
    'driver'    => env('DB_CONNECTION'),
    'host'      => env('DB_HOST'),
    'port'      => env('DB_PORT'),
    'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE'),
    'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME'),
    'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD'),
    'charset'   => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    'prefix'    => '',
]);

$capsule->setAsGlobal();
$capsule->bootEloquent();
?>
```

3. I upload the whole Laravel folder outside the root folder, named `laravel`. The folder structure is updated as follow:

```
/laravel
  /app
    /Http
    /Models
      Task.php
    ..etc
  /bootstrap
  /config
  ..etc
/css
/images
/js
bootstrap.php
index.php
```

4. In the `index.php` which I want to use the Eloquent model, I add the followings:

**index.php**

```
<?php
require_once('bootstrap.php');
require_once('../laravel/app/Models/Task.php');

use Illuminate\Database\Connection as DB;

$task = App\Models\Task::find(1);
var_dump($task);
?>
```

I think this is a minimal working example.

Comment: Now I ask out of curiosity, why would you need to "remove" or "split" the app like this ? What are you facing that needs this to be done ? I am asking because I helped a lot of people and worked with this for years in a lot of different projects and I never saw or had to do this.

Comment: The PHP codes outside the Laravel app are old; converting / refactoring / upgrading them takes time. Maybe I will merge it with the Laravel app later.

Comment: Oh, I see... I would still migrate everything to Laravel instead of just a part. It will be a pain later to migrate those assets to Laravel...